# Solving non-linear programming with large number of variables

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, [n] = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and consider the following optimization problem:

$$\max \sum_{i \in [n]} \sum_{j \in [n]} x_i \cdot x_j \cdot c_{i,j}$$
$$s.t.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$
$$\forall q \in Q: ~~~~~\sum_{i \in S_q} x_i \leq 1$$
$$\forall i \in [n]~~~~~~~~~~~~~x_i \geq 0$$
where $S_q \subseteq [n]$ for every $q \in Q$ and $c_{i,j} \in \mathbb{N}$ for every $i,j \in [n]$. Let $m = |Q|$; assume that $m = \log(n)$, that is, the number of variables is exponential in the number of nontrivial constraints. Further, assume that $|S_q| = m^{O(1)}$ for all $q \in Q$.

**Question:** Under what conditions can we get an $\alpha$-approximation for this problem in time $m^{O(1)}$?

If this was a linear program (LP), I would find the dual problem and try to solve it using the ellipsoid method by constructing a separation oracle. Is there a similar analog for such a (non-linear) program with a large number of variables?

Comment: How could you possibly do time $m^{O(1)} = \log^{O(1)} n$, when just representing the input (or the output) takes space polynomial in $n$?  Maybe you are imagining the input is given in some implicit representation?  If so you need to say explicitly what it is.  Likewise for the output.  Also, something else funny: with your assumptions, at most polylog$(n)$ variables occur in constraints, and any variable that doesn't can be set to an arbitrarily large value.  So (unless the number of positive $c_{ij}$ is at most polylog $n$), the optimization problem must be unbounded.

Comment: ... For it not to be unbounded, it must be that, for every positive $c_{ij}$, both $x_i$ and $x_j$ are one of the polylog$(n)$ variables that occur in a constraint.  For that to happen, there must be only polylog$(n)$ positive $c_{ij}$'s.  So why not assume that is the case, and that the input encoding explicitly lists only the positive $c_{ij}$'s.  Then the input encoding has size polylog$(n) = $ poly$(m)$.  So the instance is equivalent to a poly$(m)$-size instance of the same problem without your stated restrictions, and you are asking for a poly-time algorithm for such an instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quadratic program (QP). If the matrix $C$ where $(C)_{i,j} = c_{i,j}$ is positive semi definite, then the problem is convex. It seems that your problem should have non-empty interior, so if it is convex, strong duality holds. Thus you could solve the dual problem using the Ellipsoid method, assuming you have a separation oracle for the dual constraints.

If the problem is not convex then I am not sure what can be done.